# How to check the form elements in the loop?

Tags: php, html, loops

I'm trying to print variables using the form elements in a loop. I'm trying to make a simple demo with this code snippet.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$ready = false;
while ($i<=60):?>


<form name="demo" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="tester" value="<?php echo $i ?>">
     <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


<?php 
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && !$ready){
  $i++;
  $ready = true;
} else {
  break;
}
  endwhile;
?>
```

I terminate the loop with the "break;" command at startup.With a simple condition, I aims to move to the second part of the loop.But, an error occurs here.
Because the loop creates a new input.Whereas it needs to print into the already existing input.

*output=*

[ 1 ] (submit) => **click**

[ 2 ] (submit) => new input

`<input type="text" name="tester" value="1">`

`<input type="text" name="tester" value="2">`

*output that should b=*

[ 1 ] (submit) => **click**

[ **2** ] (submit) => No new input. Only value variable has been updated.

`<input type="text" name="tester" value="1">` => value="**2**"

Comment: Javascript can be used or not?

Comment: @BhaumikBhatt No, actually, I want to use ajax.

Comment: You want to print 1,2,3...60 inside the input box right?

Comment: @BhaumikBhatt yes right.

Comment: @loritasker could you please rephrase your question? It is very difficult to understand what is your goal here.

Comment: @Jinksy The inputbox copies itself in every loop.I just want the inputbox value to change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a loop for that, (unless you really need it for some reason) below code should suffice

```
<?php
$value = 1;
if (isset($_POST['tester'])) {
    $new_value = intval($_POST['tester']);
    if ($new_value > 0 && $new_value < 60) {
        $value = $new_value + 1;
    } elseif ($new_value == 60) {
        $value = $new_value;
    }
}
?>
<form name="demo" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="tester" value="<?php echo $value ?>">
     <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```